# Drawing line on iPhone X

Tags: ios, drawing, iphone-x

I have drawing functionality in my app over photo. It's working on every device except iPhone X. On iPhone X the lines become fade and move upwards with each finger movement. The upper 10-20 percent area of view works fine. Following is the code to draw line.

```
- (void)drawLineNew{

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
[self.viewImage drawInRect:self.bounds];

CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.selectedColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), _lineWidth);
CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), previousPoint.x, previousPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);

CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
self.viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[self setNeedsDisplay];}
```

Following is the sample drawing screenshot
[image]

Comment: It looks like you have a blur view (UIVisualEffectView) overlaid on top of your view. Do you have anything in your UI that is doing blurring?

Comment: I have checked all the view hierarchy in debug mode and there is no other view. Thats what making this more difficult to track.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of hit and trial I made it work. The code I wrote is correct and should be working. The only issue was the frame size of that drawingView (self). 
The height of view was in float and that was making it to go upwards with each pixel. I applied `lroundf` function and its working.
Happy coding.